# Difference between video captured with Google Earth and Google Earth Pro

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-pro

Is there any difference between video which is captured with Google Earth and Google Earth Pro? Maybe some kind of tag showing 'pro'?

Answer (score 2):

You can't produce movies on the free Google Earth software (at least with my current version on OSX).  There is a Google Earth tag placed on the video from the Pro version, and you have the option to produce videos with a range of resolution. For still images, you can produce a range of different image sizes also.